# Convert .CSV to .XLSX using command line

Tags: csv, command-line, vbscript

I'm looking for a way to batch-convert a series of `.csv` files to `.xlsx` using the command line.

I have tried a bunch of different VBScripts that I found but they all seem to be converting `.xlsx` to `.csv` and not the other way around.

Here is the closest one I could find but again it's `.xlsx` to `.csv`:

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv"
    Wscript.Quit
End If
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
oBook.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1), 6
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

only pre-requisite is that the ".csv" must be lower case in the filename:

```
Dim file, WB

With CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each file In WScript.Arguments
        Set WB = .Workbooks.Open(file)
        WB.SaveAs Replace(WB.FullName, ".csv", ".xlsx"), 51
        WB.Close False
    Next    
    .Quit
End With

WScript.Echo "Done!"
```

Comment: I launched it from the command line with a single .csv file as the argument but it just says done and nothing happens.

Comment: have you passed arguments to it? and are you calling the script from CMD, or using it directly through drag-n-drop?

Comment: So i got your method to work i just needed to pass the absolute path not just the file name. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use `Replace(WB.FullName, ".csv", ".xlsx", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)` and you don't need to worry about case. Or `Replace(LCase(WB.FullName), ".csv", ".xlsx")`.

Comment: @Bond good shout, although I avoided `LCase()` because the output filename is then all lower case. Pedantic I know but hey ho...

Comment: @Andrew not sure what you're referring to? This uses the `.SaveAs` method in Excel to save a copy of the file as a CSV - it's not just renaming the file, which obviously wouldn't work. The example you pointed to also isn't a script that would run in the command line

Answer (score 21):

Disclaimer: I have written CSV2XLSX available as open-source at https://gitlab.com/DerLinkshaender/csv2xlsx

You may want to try an external tool like the one above. Why?

Advantages:

- may be used even where Windows Script Host is blocked.
- independent of operating system, so you may use a familiar tool with then same set of options on every OS (save brain memory :-) ).
- no installation of Excel or LibreOffice etc. needed, so you don't have to care about installing additional modules or languages.
- specifying several CSV parameters as command-line parameters makes the tool "SysAdmin-friendly", as they do not have to dig thru source code.
- you may even specify line or column ranges for the csv data.
- the xlsx file format is very complex, writing it without resorting to an installation of an office package is not for the faint of heart.
- better suited for batch processing as the tool can be integrated in the OS-specific loop logic.
- I tried to provide a useful set of command line flags with DevOps/SysAdmin in mind, many existing scripts lack good control via command-line options.

Comment: Providing link is ok, try to explain how this will solve the problem in question.

Comment: @ArunVinoth - thanks, better now? I'm a newcomer to SO.

Comment: +1.
Seems to work fine after a few tests.  Here is the 2 lines batch file I made to convert files with a simple drag'n drop : `csv2xlsx_amd64.exe -colsep ";"  -sheet "data"  -outfile "%1.xlsx" -infile "%1"
` `pause`.
The result may look a bit ugly (I'd love to have a font parameter to set Tahoma instead of Verdana), but it seems to do a nice job.
The performance is decent too.  Not extremely fast, but I wouldn't call it slow.
I just had one a (very stupid) issue : tried to use " -noheader yes" while noheader uses no parameter, which resulted in a wrong error (*input file doesn't exist.*)

Comment: @Balmipour I enhanced the tool. There are now options for FontName, FontSize as well as a filemask for wildcard/bulk processing and many more, including support for other encodings than UTF-8

Comment: @user121391 other encodings are now possible, have a look at the new release

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, I recently responded to a similar question on SuperUser.com.

https://superuser.com/a/1011154/326177

I think **Total CSV Converter** is the least expensive option with the most features. It doesn't even require Excel to be installed and can can output CSV data to JSON, Access, DBF, XML or SQL.

http://www.coolutils.com/TotalCSVConverter

```
CSVConverter.exe <source> <destination> <options>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a open-source tool for Windows machines I created using the NPOI libraries that does simple delimited file to XLS/XLSX conversions without Excel needing to be installed on the machine.  The binary is in Bin/Debug if you don't want to build it yourself.  All the necessary libraries are included in the executable so it can operate standalone.

https://github.com/nmolinos/csv2excel

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows or Linux/Mac?

I might have a solution for you either way.

Here is the solution to your problems without the programs commented below:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74df1378-7c0c-4c0f-b174-fa97a5c2969b/convert-csv-to-xlsx?forum=Vsexpressvb

**EDIT**
So here is the basic solution:

Basically you apply a filter (which in the case would be the xlsx filter) from the directory where your file is located.

**Nvm this I just saw you are on Windows**
 ./directory --headless --convert-to xlsx:"Calc MS Excel 2007 XML" file.csv

in this case "Calc MS Excel 2007 XML" is the filter.

That works for single files, let me add batch in a sec.

Comment: Sorry i should have mentioned windows

Comment: Try these out, they are useful converters for Windows

http://www.dbf2002.com/csv-converter/commandline.html

http://www.softinterface.com/Convert-XLS/Features/Convert-CSV-To-XLSX.htm

Comment: Ive tried both of those and they both convert them incorrectly and results in an error when i try to import them using SSIS to my SQL database, however if i do it manually through excel it works perfectly