# How can I use absolute path in batch file or force vbs not to need the path?

Tags: csv, vbscript

I am writing a batch file and part of it converts .csv to .xlsx. I've been able to incorporate the solution from this post:

[Convert .CSV to .XLSX using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606394/convert-csv-to-xlsx-using-command-line)

```
Dim file, WB

With CreateObject("Excel.Application")
On Error Resume Next
For Each file In WScript.Arguments
    Set WB = .Workbooks.Open(file)
    WB.SaveAs Replace(WB.FullName, ".csv", ".xlsx"), 51
    WB.Close False
Next    
.Quit
End With
```

It works great, but the only issue is that I must pass an absolute path into the batch file to get it to work, like so:

```
CSV2XLSX.vbs C:\Users\Data\ktq\abc.csv
```

As explained in the original thread, it doesn't work just by doing the following:

```
CSV2XLSX.vbs abc.csv
```

This is a bit of a pain as if I move the folder I need to update the path. Is there any way I can force vbs to just take in the above command by correctly finding the file, or can I get the absolute path from the file in question and pass it in somehow? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script will provide you with the path of your running `.vbs` script. You can use such script to determine the path of your files.
So if, for instance, your script is stored in `C:\Users\Data\ktq\yourscript.vbs", the script bellow will output`strMainPath`as`C:\Users\Data\ktq` (without the trailing backslash):

```
Dim objShell : Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Dim strPath : strPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objFile : Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
Dim strMainPath : strMainPath = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile) 

'Cleaning no longer needed objects
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing

Print strMainPath
```

So, supposing your script is in the same folder as your `.csv` files, you will be able to find them all. If you have another level of files, say in `C:\Users\Data\ktq\myFiles\` you will also be good to go if you just change the `Print` part of the code above with this:

```
Print strMainPath & "\myFiles\"
```

Adapting it to your code, it should be something like this:

```
Dim objShell : Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Dim strPath : strPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objFile : Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
Dim strMainPath : strMainPath = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile) 

'Cleaning no longer needed objects
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing

Dim file, WB

With CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each file In WScript.Arguments
        Set WB = .Workbooks.Open(strMainPath & "\" & file)
        WB.SaveAs Replace(WB.FullName, ".csv", ".xlsx"), 51
        WB.Close False
    Next    
    .Quit
End With
```